How to generate rocket.chat react-native app debugger, release build along with apk file
I've been trying to run the project after cloning it from GitHub, but I can't start it. I'm new to React Native and followed the React Native documentation to set up the environment.
When I run this command.
npx react-native run-android
I get this errors.

warn Package react-native-screens has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: "dependency.platforms.android.componentDescriptors" is not allowed
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 4660 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\6.9\scripts\6i9i9bnddw9jia40cuwkefhq4).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 61


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\username.gradle\caches\6.9\scripts\6i9i9bnddw9jia40cuwkefhq4).


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'BuildScript' Unsupported class file major version 61


Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 2s
at makeError (C:\Users\username\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\username\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\username\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\username\Dropbox\PC\Desktop\freelance\Rocket.Chat.ReactNative\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)

